# Turning a string in to a reference of an object

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a dynamic stored procedure from a database. The parameters for the stored procedure are select from another stored procedure.

I need to be able to reference a session object for example from a string held within a database field.

How do I turn a string into a reference to the Session object. For example:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@test", rdr["fldValue"].ToString()));
```

The value of fldValue is "`Session["SessionParam"].ToString()`"

What I would like is to be turn the string into a reference of an object so I would get the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@test", Session["SessionParam"].ToString()));
```

I would like to reference the value of any object but am looking at the `Session` object initially.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like `string key = "SessionParam";`, `Session[key]`? It can't be that simple... And what is the "any object"? `Session` as objects with string-base keys - most objects do not have that. Can you please explain what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Are you trying to have the database update automatically whenever that value in the session changes? You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", Session["SessionParam"].ToString());
```